# What is a formula expressing the sequence where the consecutive terms are the squares of the squares of previous terms or any similar sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I express this sequence? (I made it up, but don't know how to express it):

$2^2=4$

$4^2=16$

$16^2=256$

$256^2=65536$

$65536^2=4294967296$

$...$

This sequence grows amazingly fast! How would you express it?

My attempt: if $b$ is the initial base, $p$ is the power for a general case:

$t_1=b^p$

$t_{n+1}=t_n^p$

Is there a better way to express this? 
Just curious. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the original sequence, $t_n=2^{2^n}$. For the generalised sequence, $t_n=b^{p^n}$.

These are double exponential functions. They grow faster than single exponentials and factorials.

Answer (score 1):

$$ 2^{\left( 2^n \right)}  $$

Usually people leave out any parentheses.